# Touch-friendly LXDE app launcher

Tags: gnome3, lxde, touch

I am about to make a tablet with a raspberry pi and would like an interface for launching apps that is touch-friendly. The gnome app launcher seems very well suited for this to me. Because of the limited hardware, I want to stay with LXDE. Is it possible to use the Gnome app launcher in LXDE? If not, does anybody know a touch-friendly alternative?

Comment: LXDE is great! But I am not sure about X and touchscreens. KDE and GNOME are usinf Wayland. Have you advanced on this project? I am interested (:

Comment: I am looking for something similar, I may end just installing android on the PI